# VB RaiseEvent not being picked up by Form

Tags: vb.net

The basic problem is I have a form (Form A) that opens another form (Form B for now) to edit information in Form A. When Form B is done, it should refresh the information in Form A.

To accomplish this, I create in Form B

```
Public Event Saved(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

And then call it with

```
RaiseEvent Saved(sender, e)
```

I know that the RaiseEvent line is executing (if I set breakpoints and step over the debugger lands on it), but then the line in Form A that should be picking up the event

```
Private Sub frmContactPrefixDel_Saved(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)      Handles frmContactPrefixDel.Saved
```

Where `frmContactPrefixDel` points to Form B doesn't pick up the event and execute it's lines. If I set a breakpoint on that line it doesn't even get to that sub at all. Any obvious problems? I'm new to object oriented programming, but I can't see where I've gone wrong. It seems simple to me. Also, intellisense in Visual Studio 2015 is picking up the `.Saved` on the end of `frmContactPrefixDel` so I don't think it's a scope issue.

I realize I'm making assumptions here as someone new to the game. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: If you are going to use the Handles keyword to subscribe then you must use the WithEvents keyword in the event declaration.  Right now you must use the AddHandler statement.  Why the compiler did not yell at you about it is not terribly clear.

Comment: Sorry I did actually use the WithEvents handler, `Public WithEvents frmContactPrefixDel As fContactPrefixDel`. Turns out my problem was I did that and then a line a little later I did `Dim frmContactPrefixDel...` so I was confusing things.. Thanks for rubberducking.